# Loading angular seems to change browser stylesheet

Tags: angularjs

when I include angularjs javascript file in my app it causes some text to appear smaller on the page and it is slightly screwing up some paddings and stuff...

Has anyone else experienced this?  Do you know what angular is changing in the browser stylesheet?

If I comment out the script ref to angularjs the problem goes away...
If I load my stylesheet after angularjs the problem goes away...

UPDATE:

The problem was not caused by angular.js.  I was also including angular-* (angular-mocks, angular-sanitize, angular-scenario, etc...)  One of these other files was injecting serious css.  But that is good I found this because they shouldn't have been including anyways.

Comment: Is this the case for every browser? In which browsers do have you seen this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular does indeed inject some CSS into the page, but this usually does not effect the appearance of you HTML. It is required for the [`ngCloak`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angCloak) directive to work correctly.

Injected CSS:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but for anyone else reading please note this should never cause style issues.  I was including other angular files which was the issue...